# Network issue ubuntu 20.04 - some website can't be reached

Tags: networking

Since today, I cannot access some website through the browser or by pinging it in the terminal while others remain accessible. I am on ubuntu 20.04 and i haven't done any network settings change or what so ever.
For instance [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) or [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com) are accessible but [www.github.com](http://www.github.com) or [www.askubuntu.com](http://www.askubuntu.com) aren't.

[ping youtube VS github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65Q5y.jpg)

As you can see , YouTube.com is pinging correctly but GitHub throws

```
ping : connect : Network is unreachable
```

I am also adding the content of systemd.conf:

```
If that helps : 
the systemd.conf content
`  GNU nano 4.8               /etc/systemd/resolved.conf                         
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See resolved.conf(5) for details

[Resolve]
#DNS=
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#LLMNR=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#DNSSEC=no
#DNSOverTLS=no
#Cache=no-negative
#DNSStubListener=yes
#ReadEtcHosts=yes`
```

What I get if I run `sudo apt-get update`

```
Err:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Could not resolve 'de.archive.ubuntu.com'
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Err:4 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Could not resolve 'de.archive.ubuntu.com'
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Err:6 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Could not resolve 'de.archive.ubuntu.com'
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thierry-f/fork-michael-gruz/ubuntu focal InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                                
W: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Could not resolve 'de.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'de.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Could not resolve 'de.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have seen that for some similar issues the ouput of tracepath can be relevant therefore I add here too ():

```
 tracepath google.com
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                        0.030ms pmtu 1500
 1:  2a02:8071:aeb:8200:7254:25ff:fe58:f20b                7.085ms 
 1:  2a02:8071:aeb:8200:7254:25ff:fe58:f20b                6.447ms 
 2:  2a02:8071:a00::1                                     24.160ms 
 3:  2a02:8071:ff:37c0::1                                 20.167ms 
 4:  de-str01c-rc1-lo0-0.v6.aorta.net                     20.573ms asymm  5 
 5:  de-fra04d-rc1-lo0-0.v6.aorta.net                     19.275ms 
 6:  no reply
 7:  no reply
 8:  no reply
 9:  no reply
10:  no reply
 
tracepath github.com
 1:  send failed
     Resume: pmtu 65535 

tracepath ebay.com
 1:  send failed
     Resume: pmtu 65535 

 tracepath youtube.com
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                        0.015ms pmtu 1500
 1:  2a02:8071:aeb:8200:7254:25ff:fe58:f20b               13.594ms 
 1:  2a02:8071:aeb:8200:7254:25ff:fe58:f20b                9.654ms 
 2:  2a02:8071:a00::1                                    412.341ms 
 3:  2a02:8071:ff:37c0::1                                 17.899ms 
 4:  de-str01c-rc1-lo0-0.v6.aorta.net                     21.356ms asymm  5 
 5:  de-fra01b-rc2-lo0-0.v6.aorta.net                     24.844ms 
 6:  no reply
 7:  no reply
 8:  no reply

 ping ebay.com
ping: connect: Network is unreachable

 ping github.com
ping: connect: Network is unreachable

 ping youtube.com
PING youtube.com(fra07s30-in-x200e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:803::200e)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fra24s02-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:803::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=115 time=41.1 ms
64 bytes from fra24s02-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:803::200e): icmp_seq=2 ttl=115 time=57.1 ms
64 bytes from fra24s02-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:803::200e): icmp_seq=3 ttl=115 time=26.9 ms
64 bytes from fra24s02-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:803::200e): icmp_seq=4 ttl=115 time=22.2 ms
64 bytes from fra24s02-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:803::200e): icmp_seq=5 ttl=115 time=24.7 ms
64 bytes from fra24s02-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:803::200e): icmp_seq=6 ttl=115 time=31.0 ms
64 bytes from fra24s02-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:803::200e): icmp_seq=7 ttl=115 time=28.9 ms
64 bytes from fra24s02-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:803::200e): icmp_seq=8 ttl=115 time=25.7 ms
64 bytes from fra24s02-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:803::200e): icmp_seq=9 ttl=115 time=24.4 ms
64 bytes from fra24s02-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:803::200e): icmp_seq=10 ttl=115 time=74.2 ms
64 bytes from fra24s02-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:803::200e): icmp_seq=11 ttl=115 time=78.4 ms
64 bytes from fra24s02-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:803::200e): icmp_seq=12 ttl=115 time=74.9 ms
64 bytes from fra24s02-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:803::200e): icmp_seq=13 ttl=115 time=25.9 ms
^C
--- youtube.com ping statistics ---
13 packets transmitted, 13 received, 0% packet loss, time 12018ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 22.158/41.177/78.385/20.963 ms
```

I also looked up the results of `nslookup`

```
 nslookup google.com
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 142.250.186.46
Name:   google.com
Address: 2a00:1450:4001:801::200e

 nslookup github.com
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   github.com
Address: 140.82.121.4
```

The IP adress from github is indeed leading to github.com if i try on another system. therefore probably a DNS problem. But sofar didn't manage to solve it

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks

---

I have managed to solve partially the problem.
As long as I am connected directly to the main router everything works fine but as soon as I am connected to a wifi repeater the connection problems start. The conection to a repeater was till the last 24 h not a problem.
If anyone has a solution for this problem I would be more than happy to take it.

Comment: Thank you karel, I tried to add `nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.4.4` as suggested in the other post. Unfortunately it didn't solve it. I am still unable to run `apt-get update` without error.
However what is interesting is that in the borwser I can access: us.archive.ubuntu.com but I cannot access de.archive.ubuntu.com 
I do not know if this is relevant but it is quite intriguing.

Comment: For the sake of completeness I have reset to factory the rooter and it did not solve the issue.

Comment: Little update here, I even tried a fresh install of ubuntu 20.04.3 on one of the machines and the problem persists!

Answer (score -1):

isn't it from your router or internet provider?
also you can check *setting > network > network proxy* and check if it is disabled, automatic or manual. change its situation and see if it solve the problem.

Comment: I have tested on my laptop also equipped with ubuntu 20.04 and I get the same problem. However on Windows 10 this is not the case.

Comment: I have changed the settings from disabled to automatic and then to manual and nothing did change. 
What surprises me is that 2 machines at my place display the same problem at the exact same they whereas one day prior no network issues were to be seen.